# Not able to disable @Html.DatePickerFor

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have @Html.DatePickerFor control as follows

```
<div id="divDate">
   @Html.DatePickerFor(model => model.DtSrc, "birthDate", "autoclose=true", "todayHighlight=true")
   <a href="#" id="anchorId">
        <img src="../calImage.png">
   </a>
</div>
```

I tried adding `"disabled=true"` but it doesn't seems to be working.
Can anybody please help.

Comment: try this:    @Html.DatePickerFor(model => model.DtSrc, new {disabled= "disabled" })

Comment: @Vikrant This gives error if I add new{disabled= "disabled" } after model